# Cache miss at a CDN edge server

Tags: caching, cdn, transport, content-delivery-network

Upon cache miss at a CDN edge server:

1. the server might redirect the end-user to another CDN server that has the content or
2. it might try to download the solicited content from the producer, cache it, and then respond to the end-user.

Now, if this understanding is right then how the second solution works for very big files (like a movie). I just do not understand how the edge server can put the end-user on hold for several minutes to download the content from the producer and then sends it to the end-user!!

Answer (score 0):

The CDN won't delay the user more than the origin (producer) would.

In the case of streaming a movie, with or without a CDN between you and the origin, you don't download the entire movie and then play it (neither does the CDN), you download the movie in chunks while playing the previously downloaded chunk (and the CDN does the same, and caches the chunks).

btw, a CDN can actually accelerate downloading big files or dynamic content, even if it doesn't hold it in cache, by accelerating TCP, and other cool techniques.

Comment: I am more thinking of how a CDN server can manage to relay the incoming byte stream from the origin down to the consumer. Assuming the consumer wants to download a big binary file through HTTP protocol, then how the server resolve the HTTP requests?

Comment: @Chavoosh what is unique in this case about having a CDN in the middle, why would that be any worse than downloading a huge file from the origin itself ?

Comment: Well, I am trying to understand how TCP's point-to-point model works with a CDN server in the middle as in this case the CDN server itself is the destination.

Comment: Well actually CDNs do interesting things when it comes to TCP. For example CloudFront maintains persistent TCP connections for acceleration.

Regardless, with no tricks or optimizations, a CDN is basically a computer that has one connection open with you, one with the origin, and forwards requests and responses back and forth.

If you are worried about the CDN's load capacity, i.e. handling huge traffic from a single user, or multiple users, that is part of what CDN engineers work on, i.e. predicting loads, redirecting traffic, having optimized quantity of hardware, etc.